# Last element is missing from the 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, 2d, fflush

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


 int main(){

    int num;

    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Enter: ");

    char nums[5][num], ch;

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            if((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
                nums[j][i] = ch;
            }
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            printf("%c ", nums[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
1
Enter: 12345
 1 2 3 4 

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.282 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Why the last element is missing and the additional space at the beginning of the output of array?

If I change the range for j in both for loops to

```
j <= 5
```

then, the output looks like this:

```
1
Enter: 12345
 1 2 3 4 5 

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.107 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

If the initial value for j is 1 in the printf loop, then the output looks like this:

```
1
Enter: 12345
1 2 3 4 5 

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.675 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

No extra gap at the beginning of the array output.

Can anyone explain this and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your first `getchar` is consuming the newline character that `scanf` left behind. Replace that with `scanf("%d ", &num);` (note the whitespace).

Comment: In general, you should avoid using `scanf` with other input methods. If you use `scanf` to read the number (using `"%d"`), then you should use `scanf` to read the characters (using `" %c"`). Note the space before the `%c`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Trailing space in scanf is a bad idea, it means input will block until they type another non-whitespace item

Comment: Normally, in C, if you have a 2D array `SomeType array[5][num];`, your loops will work on the leading index before the trailing index:  `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) { …array[i][j]… }`, but you have the code works with the indexes the other way around — so you fill columns rather than rows. That isn't automatically wrong, but it is aconventional in C (albeit the way Fortran works). You can look up 'column-major' and 'row-major' indexing — see Wikipedia on [Row-Major and Column-Major Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the function `getchar` reads all characters from the input stream including the new line character that stored in the buffer after the first call of `scanf`.

So in the loops the first character that is read is the new line character '`\n'`.
You should remove it for example the following way.

```
scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
scanf( "%*c" );
```

Comment: Another method, though not as elegant, would be to add something like `while(getchar() != '\n') continue;` after `scanf`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits although you should also check for EOF

Comment: in other words, the first call to scanf is reading char "1" and there is \n lurking in the input buffer. next, you start calling getchar(), so you get `\n 1 2 3 4` so these are your 5 elements that you are reading. The '5' one would not be read since you hardcoded 5 calls to getchar()

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic issue in the first loop.  You test for `\n` but then if you do find a `\n`, you leave the array entry uninitialized and go on to the next entry anyway. This leads to the bogus output.

Instead you could delay the `j++` until getting a valid character, e.g. :

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5;     ){
        if((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
            nums[j][i] = ch;
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the array will be filled with the non-newline characters that get entered, and you don't need to do any other flushling.

It would improve the code to also check `ch != EOF` (and `ch` should be declared as `int`), but then you will need some error handling (it would be a mistake to just break the loop and go on to try and output the whole array).